# Alternatives to using SQL IN in this query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a string holding comma separated values = value1, value2, value3 .......

I want to perform following operation:

```
SELECT col FROM table WHERE col IN :values
```

This works fine if values have less than 1000 entries. It gives error when values have more than 1000 entries. There is a limit on usage of IN.

Is there any alternative way to perform this query?

EDIT: 
It is Oracle's Business Intelligence Publisher application. Customer/User can use any database underneath.

I do not have control over database. So I cannot create a temp table or stored procedure. All I can do is select multiple values from UI screen (it forms comma separated string) and use it in a SQL query. Depending on which reports are generated.

- Cannot use EXISTS with static string values.
- Cannot use stored procedure or temp table.

Comment: What's your RDBMS?
For Oracle you could create a PL SQL function with a cursor. Although it could be an overkill. Just an idea...

Comment: MySQL, Oracle, PostGreSQL, SQL Server?  They all have different capabalities and syntax.  Is this a query from your own application?  Or is it done in a Query Manager of some kind?  Is your list of values derived from another table/query?  Etc, etc, etc?  Please give more details and context.

Comment: Are you *absolutely* sure that you can't create temp tables? Temp tables have no impact on other users, they are transient and local to your sessions. It is *unusual* to not be able to do this. Do you have any more-experienced colleagues (or a manual) that can can categorically clarify that for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
@NeilKnight
I have explored EXISTS option. However it requires another subquery using SELECT. In my case I just have a string of values to look into.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
@PanagiotisPalladinos
Any database, depends on customer.

Comment: @Dems
Thanks. It is not my own application, but sort of Query Manager (Oracle BI Publisher) you can say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *cannot* create a global temporary table, then you could convert your delimited list to rows using `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll()` and join to this collection.

```
SELECT t.col 
FROM table t
JOIN TABLE(SELECT column_value 
             FROM sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll(:values)) c on t.col = c.column_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

The most performance will take a bit of crafting. I would suggest building an in-memory temporary table that holds your values, each in one row, and then join your real table to this temporary table. This will make your query significantly faster and, as an added bonus, the number of rows in the temporary table is not limited (or rather, only limited by memory).

Answer (score 0):

You could insert the values into a temp table and then do a join:

```
SELECT col from table t1 JOIN #temp t2 WHERE table.col = t2.col;
```

Comment: Thanks @jalynn2.

I do not have control over the code. All I can do is select 'n' values from UI screen and write a query using those values.

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure to do this job for you like this:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetData] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ids nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #TempTable(col int)
while len(@ids) > 0
begin
  insert into #TempTable values (left(@ids, charindex(',', @ids+',')-1))
  set @ids = stuff(@ids, 1, charindex(',', @ids+','), '')
end
    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select col from table where col in (select col from #TempTable)
END
```

Source is from my blog: http://alisissa.wordpress.com/2012/10/24/pass-a-comma-separated-list-to-a-stored-procedure/

Comment: as you can see I created a temp table and added all the cols in it then get all the records inside this temp table, you should pass a comma delimited array

Comment: Assumes SQL Server.  As the OP is using `:values` for a parameter, that's unlikely to be correct...

Comment: it is sql since it is in the tags :) , and it will work if the parameter  passed is array of cols comma delimited

Comment: It is `SQL`, but that does ***not*** make it `SQL Server`. SQL Server uses `@param` and Oracle uses `:Param`. The use of Oracle's notation makes it unlikely that this would be for SQL Server. Also, since my comment, and before your comment, the OP has stated that this is on Oracle *(which is **not** SQL Server)*.

Answer (score 0):

We've used the following function for years to split CSV strings passed into stored procedures. (Apologies if it isn't the most modern, elegant or efficient way of doing it, but it's worked well for our purposes)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split](@text varchar(8000), @delimiter varchar(20) = ' ')
RETURNS @Strings TABLE
(    
  position int IDENTITY,
  value varchar(8000)   
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @index int 
SET @index = -1 
SET @text = LTRIM(RTRIM(@text))
WHILE (LEN(@text) > 0) 
  BEGIN  
    SET @index = CHARINDEX(@delimiter , @text)  
    IF (@index = 0) AND (LEN(@text) > 0)  
      BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (@text)
          BREAK  
      END  

    IF (@index > 1)  
      BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @Strings VALUES (LEFT(@text, @index - 1))   
        SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index))  
      END  
    ELSE 
      SET @text = RIGHT(@text, (LEN(@text) - @index)) 
    END
  RETURN
END
```

In use it's:

```
select value from dbo.fn_Split('string1,string2,string3',',')
```

(Oh, and this is for an MS SQL Server database btw)

Comment: As the OP is using `:values` for a parameter, assuming SQL Server is unlikely to be correct...

Comment: Ah fair do's, I wondered what that syntax was. Oh well, there goes today's attempt at scoring some points...